# Found my touchpad driver, but don't know how to install it

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus

I'm bad with Linux and I'm tring to enable finger gestures on my pc but there is no "touchpad' tab in the settings of my mouse.

So I searched for the driver that I need, I have a Asus TP300LA under Kali Linux v2

I found here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191820 @ Post #8 that I have to install this driver:

[image]

But I don't know how, do you have an idea ?
I think that I have to build a package..

I hope someone could help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus UX303LA with a Focaltech touchpad, whose drivers were introduced in the Linux kernel version 3.18. They are also available in Debian Jessie's 3.16 kernel.

If you don't have a 3.18+ kernel, you should try to upgrade.

By the way, if you are "bad with Linux", why are you on Kali ? It's a distro for advanced users who work on security. You really should go to Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: I think I have two different kernels.. 3.19 and 4.0 but my system boot in 3.19 by default, I'm on Kali because I want to learn using it's tools, I apparently have an "PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse" (found an alternative to "xinput list"), but I don't fin way to enable gesture/scrolling..

Comment: Use another distro. All the tools that are present out of the box on Kali are available on Debian and Ubuntu. Kali is for security professionals. I don't know what your touchpad is, but you really should use something more newbie-friendly.